# Algorithm of boost::math::erf

Tags: c++, math, boost, distribution, numerical-methods

are there any details available for the algorithm behind the erf-function of boost? The documentation of the module is not very precise. All I found out is that several methods are mixed. For me it looks like variations of Abramowitz and Stegun.

- Which methods are mixed?
- How are the methods mixed?
- What is the complexity of the erf-function (constant time)?

Sebastian

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The docs for [Boost Math Toolkit](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/) has a long list of [references](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/backgrounders/refs.html), among which Abramowitz and Stegun. The [erf-function](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/special/sf_erf/error_function.html) interface contains a [policy](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/policy.html) template parameter that can be used to control the numerical precision (and hence its run-time complexity).

```
#include <boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp>
namespace boost{ namespace math{

template <class T>
calculated-result-type erf(T z);

template <class T, class Policy>
calculated-result-type erf(T z, const Policy&);

template <class T>
calculated-result-type erfc(T z);

template <class T, class Policy>
calculated-result-type erfc(T z, const Policy&);

}} // namespaces
```

**UPDATE**:

Below a verbatim copy of the section "Implementation" of the earlier provided reference to the erf-function:

**Implementation**

All versions of these functions first use the usual reflection formulas to make their arguments positive:

```
erf(-z) = 1 - erf(z);

erfc(-z) = 2 - erfc(z);  // preferred when -z < -0.5

erfc(-z) = 1 + erf(z);   // preferred when -0.5 <= -z < 0
```

The generic versions of these functions are implemented in terms of the incomplete gamma function.

When the significand (mantissa) size is recognised (currently for 53, 64 and 113-bit reals, plus single-precision 24-bit handled via promotion to double) then a series of rational approximations devised by JM are used.

For z <= 0.5 then a rational approximation to erf is used, based on the observation that erf is an odd function and therefore erf is calculated using:

```
erf(z) = z * (C + R(z*z));
```

where the rational approximation R(z*z) is optimised for absolute error: as long as its absolute error is small enough compared to the constant C, then any round-off error incurred during the computation of R(z*z) will effectively disappear from the result. As a result the error for erf and erfc in this region is very low: the last bit is incorrect in only a very small number of cases.

For z > 0.5 we observe that over a small interval [a, b) then:

```
erfc(z) * exp(z*z) * z ~ c
```

for some constant c.

Therefore for z > 0.5 we calculate erfc using:

```
erfc(z) = exp(-z*z) * (C + R(z - B)) / z;
```

Again R(z - B) is optimised for absolute error, and the constant C is the average of erfc(z) * exp(z*z) * z taken at the endpoints of the range. Once again, as long as the absolute error in R(z - B) is small compared to c then c + R(z - B) will be correctly rounded, and the error in the result will depend only on the accuracy of the exp function. In practice, in all but a very small number of cases, the error is confined to the last bit of the result. The constant B is chosen so that the left hand end of the range of the rational approximation is 0.

For large z over a range [a, +∞] the above approximation is modified to:

```
erfc(z) = exp(-z*z) * (C + R(1 / z)) / z;
```

The rational approximations are explained in [**excruciating detail**](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/math/doc/sf_and_dist/html/math_toolkit/backgrounders/remez.html). Tf you need more details, you can always look at the [source code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/boost/math/special_functions/erf.hpp).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. With your hint to the policy template and a short review of the code I found out, that it is possible to set the number of iteration which leads to an O(1) implementation (for a constant number of iterations). But the other questions are still open. Of course the references contain Abramowitz/Stegun, but this book contains much more than only erf. Reading the code is always an option, but it consumes too much time and the algorithm should be documented in a way which makes it unnecessary to read the code.

Comment: @Euphoriewelle I updated my answer with a copy of the Implementation section of the Boost manual. I think it should answer most of your questions about implementation issues. For more details, I'm afraid the source really is the ultimate guide.

Comment: Thanks for your update! For most of the users your answer should be sufficient. I think I have no other choice and are going to read the code for the minor details.